# How work with multiple select with Devise and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a city model

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end
```

And I also use standart Devise gem for user registration and login. Now I want each user to have a multiple countries while editing his account. I added extra parameter (city_ids) as an array to Devise User model

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected


  def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up,        keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password,
city_ids: []])
  end
end
```

And I also changed my template to work with it

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :city_ids %><br />
    <%= f.select :city_ids, City.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
  </div>
```

But it doesn't write values to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `has_many :countries` to User model and then add an appropriate foreign key to your database. Take a look [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association), you'll find all the info you need

> Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :countries

   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end
```